# DataFrame Selecting row

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am trying to select a specific row from my data frames by using the .loc to take out the row and its corresponding data by the gene name, I cannot splice via number as each dataframe has different rows. The error I have been getting is a key error, although I am not sure why. I have used type(df3) to confirm that my data is still a dataframe.

```
 for name in filenames:
            df1 = pd.read_table(name, index_col=None, header = None, names =["Composite_Element_REF", "Beta_value", "Gene_Symbol", "Chromosome", "Genomic_Coordinate"], sep = "\t", skiprows= 2) # sep will seperate anything with space so it goes to the appropriate column, names is to lable column
            df1 = df1.dropna()
            df2 = df1[["Composite_Element_REF", "Beta_value","Gene_Symbol"]]
            df3 = df2.rename(columns= {"Composite_Element_REF": "Composite_Element_REF "+ str(index), "Beta_value":"Beta_value "+str(index),"Gene_Symbol":"Gene_Symbol " +str(index)}, inplace=False)
            #NR5A2 = df3.iloc[[2]]
            NR5A2 = df3.loc[("Gene_Symbol " +str(index), "NR5A2"), : ]

            index = index +1 

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-5075955b850d> in <module>()
     12     df3 = df2.rename(columns= {"Composite_Element_REF": "Composite_Element_REF "+ str(index), "Beta_value":"Beta_value "+str(index),"Gene_Symbol":"Gene_Symbol " +str(index)}, inplace=False)
     13     #NR5A2 = df3.iloc[[2]]
---> 14     NR5A2[str(index)] = df3.loc[("Gene_Symbol " +str(index), "NR5A2"), : ]
     15 
     16     index = index +1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use .loc you have to set some column as the index.

But I think you will be fine with

```
    df3[df3["Gene_Symbol " +str(index)] == 'NR5A2']
```